# How can I add all checked boxes from checklistbox to a new form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get all items from `CheckedBoxList` and add it to a new `Form` so for every checked item I want a new `Label` with checkedItem name and a `TextBox`. So far I'm doing that but when I open the form I got no results at all.  I don't know how to get the checked item name and I'm doing this:

```
labels[i].Text = i.ToString();
```

[image]

```
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testForm = new Test();
        TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel() { AutoSize = true };
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        int n = 0;

        for (int i=0;i<checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count;i++)
        {
            txtBox = new TextBox[checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count];
            labels = new Label[checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Count];

            labels[i] = new Label();
            labels[i].Text = i.ToString();
            tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(labels[i], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, n++));
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(labels[i]);

            txtBox[i] = new TextBox();
            tableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition(txtBox[i], new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, n++));
            tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(txtBox[i]);

        }
        Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
        testForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you, for the invested time.

Comment: Change `Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);` to `testForm.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);`

Comment: worked, now I need only the checked item name

Comment: Items don't have names, only Text and indices and maybe Tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the code to:

```
testForm.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
```